# CoreData and Image by URL

Tags: ios, core-data, uiimage, nsdata

In my app I receive some Json Data from web services.

I mapped this date in my Core Data model.

In some entities I have a field That Represent the URL of an image That I have to show. 
What is the better way to manage this situation?

You could add a field in my entity type NSData where to save the image  and we have, therefore, a simple cache.

Otherwise I can implement a real cache to get the images already downloaded: es: `getImageByURL` (save the images already downloaded in a directory)

Are there particular solutions in CoreData for this type of situation?

Answer (score 0):

Its really your application design decision. For any case if you want to put the whole image into the underlying table, you can use 'BinaryData' format (BLOB). There are different ways,

For app which are always online 
1. Store the URL to your core data and fetch from URL.

For Offline Support.
1. Store the image as blob
2. Store to documents folder and have the reference to file in core data
3. Use a Web-cache supported third party library and store the URL. When you fetch the URL again, the web cache would return the image which is cached. This can preferred over other two if the content has to be cycled some time and needs offline mode.

Comment: Storing this type of data in the Documents folder would violate the iOS Data Storage Guidelines, and could lead to an app being rejected during review. The URL loading system also already caches data for you, adding another layer of caching is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Two cases we have to handle
 - online
 - offline

**1. online**:

- if your app supports only online then it is better to use the following one
  https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading

  **Steps to use**
- First download and drag the folder to your project
- first add this line to your file  `#import "EGOImageView.h"`
- add the following code to add your imageurl directly

EGOImageView *egoImgView = [[EGOImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 290, 118)];
        complaintImgView.imageURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imageURLString];

**2. offline:**

- If your app supports both online and offline, just save the image name in coredata, download and save the image in documents path.
- the following is the code to save image in documents path with name saved in the coredata.

`#define` DOCUMENTS_PATH [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Download"]

**To Store image in Documents path**

```
- (void)saveImageSynchronouslyInDocumentsWithUrl:(NSString *)serverImageURL withName:(NSString` `*)coredataImageName`
    {
 NSLog(@"Synchronous Image urls %@",serverImageURL);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: imageUrl];

NSString *imagePath = [DOCUMENTS_PATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

NSError *error = nil;

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error: &error];
if (!error) {
    [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

}
}
```

**To retrieve image from Documents path**

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",DOCUMENTS_PATH, coredataImageName]];
```